# How can I access ssl enabled site from client computers in wamp server 2.5 running in localhost?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, wamp, virtualhost

I managed to create my own OPENSSL enabled sites in localhost wampserver 2.5. I  have 7 clients computers. I can access the site from these 7 clients computer without the `https://`. I installed wamp on my Drive `C:/wamp` but I put my site file in drive `D:/sites`. So my `httpd-ssl.conf` file goes:

`httpd-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    DocumentRoot "D:/sites"
    ServerName local.client:443
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    #SSLCertificateFile and ssl related goes here
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
   <Directory "D:/sites">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
    </Directory>
     BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    #custom log
  </VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access the site from the 7 client machines using `https://local.client/`, It points to wamp default site directory (www). There is no error message as well. On the server machine (the machine where I installed wamp), it is working fine. So for client machines, I added the same virtualhost tag to `httpd-vhosts.conf` and added the following code for port 80 so that I can access without `https://`

`httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/sites"
    ServerName local.client:443
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    #SSLCertificateFile and ssl related goes here
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
   <Directory "D:/sites">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
    </Directory>
     BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    #custom log
  </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/sites"
    ServerName local.client
    <Directory "D:/sites">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So the `http://` is working great in the 7 client machines. But `https://` is not working at all. There is no error message, it just directs me to `index.php` in `www` folder. So can anyone help me figure out where I go wrong, or is this something possible to do in apache2.4.9? Any advises and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You need to specify the IP address to bind to. On port 80 you are binding to all, but on 443 you are using a named default which might be localhost only.

Comment: I already tried that but it did not work out. Ok I will mention it in the question.

Comment: I don't understand people who downvote question without any explanation, which comes out of hard work and toils.

Comment: @KirkBeard, thanks for your concern. The question is about how I can access ssl enabled from client machines. Any way I could set up ssl on wamp server. But my problem is I could not access it from client machines.

Comment: @Kirk Beard, At least you can upvote it so that it attracts more expert people. That way you can help me. Thanks again.